# Porque stopPropagation() no funciona en este caso?

Tags: javascript, html5

Lo que quiero es q cuando le de click al div solo se ejecute el evento del div y no el del header, porque en el caso mio se esta ejecutando el evento del div y del header
Se supone que `stopPropagation()`haria lo que busco pero no lo hace, porque ocurre esto?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<style>
 header
 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: aqua;
 }
 div
 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
 }
</style>
<script>
 var header=document.getElementsByTagName("header");
 var div=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
 function carga()
 {
  header[0].addEventListener("click",clickheader,"false");
  div[0].addEventListener("click",clickdiv,"false");
 }
 function clickheader()
 {
  alert("hola header");
 }
 function clickdiv(e)
 {   e.stopPropagation();
  alert("hola div");
 }
 window.addEventListener("load",carga,"false");
</script>
<body>
 <header>
  <div>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El `stopPropagation()` está en el div no en el header. ¿Te refieres a por qué se ejecuta el evento del header antes del del div?

Comment: Lo que quiero es q cuando le de click al div solo se ejecute el evento del div y no el del header, porque en el caso mio se esta ejecutando el evento del div y del header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en el tercer parámetro ([useCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) de tus `addEventListener`. Dicho parámetro tiene que ser *false* para que sea un *Bubble Event* (que es lo que podes detener con un `.stopPropagation()`). Si es *true*, funciona en modo *Capture*.

Básicamente en el modo *bubble* el evento se ejecuta desde el elemento hasta arriba de todo el DOM. En *capture* al revés.

El parámetro lo tenés definido como `"false"` el *string false*, lo cual se evalúa como *verdadero*. Reemplazalos por un *false* a secas, sin comillas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta efectivamente estás en lo correcto